# php_soap not working on NGinx

Tags: php, soap

We have moved our websites from Apache 2.4 to NGinx and ever since our Soap operations are not working.

We use PHP 5.6 on a Centos 6 server, I have installed php_soap by:

> yum install php_soap php56_soap

Restarted Nginx service, php_fpm service , the server itself, verified that php_soap is installed when running:

> php -m | grep soap
>   soap

And the result is still the same:

> Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in...

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "rpm -qa php\*" will help to understand which stack are really used. Also the reported by "phpinfo" (from RPM) about loaded ini file. And of course FPM need to be restarted after new extension installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using php-fpm, the php-soap version I was installing was incorrect. Enabling the correct remi repository helped out on this case.

`yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-soap`